# Filter records based on groups of fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here's the thing - I need to filter records based on groups of fields. A prototype would look like this:

```
select distinct ID, Name from Item i 
inner join (select ItemID from ItemD where ItemDID in (146,147)) idd1 on i.ItemID = idd1.ItemID 
inner join (select ItemID from ItemD where ItemDID in (7641, 7648)) idd2 on i.ItemID = idd2.ItemID
```

(repeat inner join couple more times)

I know that I can create a stored procedure that uses sp_executesql and feed it those inner joins from my app, but I can't help wondering is there a better solution?

Comment: I can't understand what is your problem. You are looking for better way to use this query or pass this range values? First of all: WHERE ItemID IN (xxx) OR ItemID IN (yyy) OR ItemID IN (zzz) will be much faster than multiple joins way.

Comment: I could draw you a lot of clouds to explain the difference between my question and your "proposed" answer, but that would be a waste of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a temporary table, probably faster than a lot of joins:

```
Conditions:  GroupID, ItemDID
```

And fill it like:

```
1, 146
1, 147
2, 7641
2, 7648
```

Then demand that each condition group is satisfied:

```
select  ID
,       Name
from    Item i
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Conditions c
        left join    
                ItemID idd
        on      idd.ItemDID = c.ItemDID
                and idd.ItemID = i.ItemID
        group by
                c.GroupID
        having  count(idd.ItemDTD) = 0
        )
```

(Query not tested; there are many varieties.)